When solving an absolute value function, if the isolated absolute value term is equal to a negative number will the function never have x-intercepts?
Here's the question and answer from Openstax College Algebra Textbook that led to my confusion:

Question:
When solving an absolute value function, the isolated absolute value term is equal to a negative number. What does that tell you about the graph of the absolute value function?
Answer: The graph of the absolute value function does not cross the x-axis, so the graph is either completely above or completely below the x-axis.

I don't think the answer is true for all the absolute value functions. Let's say $f(x)=|x|-2$ and I'm solving for  $f(x)=-3$, I'll eventually get to $-1=|x|$. At this point "isolated absolute value term is equal to a negative number", but the graph of $f$ does cross the $x$-axis (at $2$ and $-2$).
What am I missing here? Is there a different definition of "solving an absolute value function" that I'm unaware of?
Edit: Here's a video explanation of the Q&A: https://youtu.be/8JHb-RPqB08?list=PLZBnAG03572riK3KtGrTnpGNGn2fi-zDm&t=65

"the isolated absolute value term is equal to a negative number." means "$|\text{stuff}| = -7$", for instance.  This means there's no solution.

@EricTowers Of course, but the answer says it also means that the graph does not cross the x-axis, which I found to be false for $f(x)=|x|-2$.

" so the graph is either completely above or completely below the x-axis." is wrong.  The graph of the absolute value function is always on or above the $x$-axis, never below.

@EricTowers $f(x)=-|x| - 2$ is below the $x$-axis. Are you referring to just vanilla absolute value function $f(x)=|x|$, the one without any transformation?

(1) You haven't isolated the absolute value term.  (2) This $f$'s graph is not "The graph of the absolute value function".

This is very poorly phrased. I have no idea what "when solving an absolute value function " means.  What does it mean to solve a function? What is "an absolute value function"?

@lulu I feel the same way, maybe I should use some other textbook to learn College Algebra

If this is typical for that source, I'd definitely find another.  I expect that whatever they are asking is easy enough, but it's very hard to guess their meaning.

The accepted answer is wrong, and bending over very backwards to make excuses for the OP's garbage textbook: (1) A function cannot be "solved" (an equation can), though we can certainly zero it. (2) To "isolate" a term is just ambiguous phrasing and does not have to mean making the term the subject (of an equation). @lulu

@ryang I agree that the way the terminology was used may not be fully aligned with the rigorous definitions. However, the core concept communicated by the textbook and my answer is still correct, and (at least in my experience), teachers have used the phrase "solve the function" to mean "find the roots of the function".

@VV_721 "the core concept communicated by the textbook" I'd echo lulu's comments above that the author's baby talk is quite indecipherable; in other words, this is a failure of communication, not a failure at being rigorous. (Read the quoted question, and count how many leaps and assumptions the reader has to make to guess that the author is merely asking....wait, what actually are they asking? I've just commented under your answer to point out that your guess/stab likely isn't correct. Couldn't they have bothered redrafting their stream of consciousness?)

@ryang Yeah, those are all valid points. I also had trouble understanding the problem, but after looking through the online textbook that the OP referenced, I realized what the question meant, and I just wanted to help Ajay understand as well so he could move on from the lesson.

The phrase “solving a function” means finding its $x$-intercepts, or in other words, when $f(x)=0$. For example, if you have the function $f(x)=|x|+5$, and you need to solve this function, then you have to set it equal to zero, as shown below:
$|x|+5=0$
Then you use algebra to isolate the $x$ variable:
$|x|=-5$
As you can see here, there are no real solutions for $f(x)$ because the absolute value of $x$ cannot be negative. Therefore, the graph of $f(x)$ does not touch the $x$-axis. I believe this is what the textbook was saying.

@ryang The equation $|x|=-5$ is just a step in finding the roots of $f(x)=|x|+5$, and $f(x)$ is indeed a function that doesn’t touch the $x$-axis.

Also, Ajay linked a timestamp for a YouTube playlist that provides the solution to the original textbook question, and it confirms that my interpretation is correct. But I still agree with you and @lulu that the wording was very ambiguous and should have been fixed.

I got thrown off when (3) you said "x does not have any real solutions" (variables do not have solutions), which doesn't facilitate skimming. Anyhow, I just don't feel that bending baby talk into coherence should involve pretending that the baby talk is actually coherent (e.g., a function isn't a constraint so cannot be solved without first setting it to say 7 or 0, in which case you can say that you're zeroing—not "solving", please—the function). Okay, thanks for explaining.

@ryang I just changed the wording about $x$ having solutions. It should be a little better now.
